# I cant test my .po file for Turkish Language

Tags: multi-language

I created 2 files to provide language support to my theme. .mo file contains only some info such as language creator name and some key words such as __e .

my .po file contains all text from theme and 3 translated words.

one of them is, EV it refers HOME

the other is

```
This option controls Service Details Fixed Bottom Page.Show or not.Normally, it loads demo page to bottom of service details page.You can disable or change the addition content | Turkish
```

it refers:

```
This option controls Service Details Fixed Bottom Page.Show or not.Normally, it loads demo page to bottom of service details page.You can disable or change the addition content
```

I can test 2. example which starts with "this option..." via see on redux control panel but I cant see any changing. it seems without "| Turkish" word.

I pasted these .mo and .po files to my theme main folder under language folder.

the folder contains only these 2 files.

How can I check or fix something?

I uploaded my .mo and .po files to internet.you can check them:

https://i.ibb.co/VB61ztb/image.png

the files:

https://gofile.io/d/kQQX8u

Comment: Did you properly compile your `.po` file into the `.mo` file using a `po` editor (such as `poedit`)?

Comment: @Jos I compiled just now, but still problem is exist

Comment: The `.mo` file looks good to me, it should work. Try this: put your `mo` and `po` into `wp-content/languages/themes` and rename them `[theme name].mo` and `[theme name].po`.